# How do I create a model that stores multiple images in relation to another model

Tags: python, django

How do I create a Django model `PaperImage` that stores multiple images that relates to another Django model `Papers`? And I have to afterwards access all the images related to one `Papers` object.  How should my views.py should be in order save both these relative to eachother?

```
#models.py

class Papers(models.Model):
    yearChoices = []
    grades = (
        #some grades
    )
    termChoices = (
        #some terms
    )
    for r in range(1985,(datetime.datetime.now().year)):
        yearChoices.append((r,r))

   
    subject_list = (
       #some subjects
    )

    province_list = (
        #some provinces
    )
    year = models.DateField(choices=yearChoices,default=datetime.datetime.now().year)
    term = models.CharField(choices=termChoices,default=1,max_length=15)
    subjects = models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=subject_list,help_text="Choose what subject the post belongs to.",default='u')
    grade = models.IntegerField(choices=grades,default=10)
    school = models.CharField(max_length=254,help_text="Which school's paper is this?")
    province = models.CharField(max_length=254,choices=province_list,default=1)
    education_zone = models.CharField(max_length=254,blank=True)
    
class PaperImage(models.Model):
    paper = models.OneToOneField(Papers, related_name='paper',blank=True,null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    images = CloudinaryField("images")
```

Comment: you can use `ForeignKey` to do this check this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey

Answer (score 1):

Eureka!
After some digging around, I finally got the answer. I'm posting it as an answer just in case someone stumbles upon this. Ankit Tiwari's comment really helped.

**Getting the images**

```
class Paper(models.Model):
    #Enter some stuff here
    
class PaperImage(models.Model):
    paper = models.ForeignKey(Paper,blank=True,null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    images = CloudinaryField("papers")
```

The trick was using a ForeignKey and then reverse accessing it from the `Paper` class as follows.

```
paper = Paper.objects.get(pk=1) #or any object you want really
images = paper.paperimage_set.all()
```

This returns all the `PaperImage` objects associated with the specific paper. Then its just a matter of passing them into context when rendering the web page. Then using a for loop in the template, you can easily get all the images.

```
{% for imageobject in images_list %}
        {% cloudinary imageobject.images  fetch_format='auto' width=200 height=150  %}
{% endfor %}
```

**Saving the Images**

Saving the images was another issue. That was easily fixed by getting a list of images from the `POST` request. And then passing the newly created `form_details_instance` as an attribute to create the `ForeignKey` relation between them.

```
form_details_instance = form_details.save()
            
            print('valid')
            images = request.FILES.getlist('images')
    
            for image in images:
                image_object = PaperImage(
                    paper = form_details_instance,
                    images = image
                )
                image_object.save()
```

Hope this helps anyone who has the same issue. I searched all over the internet and couldn't find a descriptive way of doing this.
PS:- I'm using a service called cloudinary to serve all my media. Other methods should be similar.