# How to upload mutiple images in the django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

It involves uploading multiple images to the django admin and the only one should show in the listings.html , and then in that instance post the other images should display there . I have done majority of the work to ensure the post is saved. Please bear in mind that i use an html page (pro.html) where i have the form my users will input whatever they want to post . Once the post in submited , it is automatically saved in the django admin . Amongst the form i require 8 images . The thing now is, if i upload 8 images it is going to save 8 times instead of once.

This is my views.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from .forms import PostForm
from django.shortcuts import render,  get_object_or_404
from .models import Post, PostImage

from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.

def post_create(request):
    form = PostForm()
   
    if request.method == 'POST':
           
            form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    
            if form.is_valid():
              form.save()
            for file in request.FILES.getlist('image'):
                image = Image(image=file)
                image.save()

    else:

        form = PostForm()

    return render(request, 'estateapp/pro.html', {'form': form})



def home(request):

    return render(request, 'estateapp/home.html')

def Listings(request):
    posts = []
    for post in Post.objects.all():
        post = {
            'title': post.title,
            'short': post.short,
            'type': post.type,
            'bedroom': post.bedroom,
            'bathroom': post.toilet,
            'toilet': post.toilet,
            'currencyfield': post.currencyfield,
            'totalarea': post.totalarea,
            'coveredarea': post.coveredarea,
            'images': post.images.url,
            'contact_methods': [
                {'name': 'Whatsapp', 'icon': 'fa-brands fa-whatsapp', 'link': 'https://wa.me/+2347064453868'},
                {'name': 'Phone', 'icon': 'fa-solid fa-phone', 'link': 'tel:+2347064453868'},
                {'name': 'Telegram', 'icon': 'fa-brands fa-telegram', 'link': ''},
                {'name': 'Instagram', 'icon': 'fa-brands fa-instagram', 'link': ''}
            ],
            'rating': 4.5
        }
        posts.append(post)
    return render(request, 'estateapp/Listings.html', {'posts': posts})

    
def post_create(request):
   
   if request.method == 'POST':
      form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

      title = request.POST['title']
      short = request.POST['short']
      category = request.POST['category']
      type = request.POST['type']
      subtype = request.POST['subtype']
      bedroom = request.POST['bedroom']
      bathroom = request.POST['bathroom']
      toilet = request.POST['toilet']
      area = request.POST['area']
      street = request.POST['street']
      availability = request.POST['availability']
      totalarea = request.POST['totalarea']
      coveredarea = request.POST['coveredarea']
      description = request.POST['description']
      
      images = request.FILES.getlist('images')
     
      currencyfield =  request.POST['currencyfield']
      url = request.POST['url']
      for image in images:
            my= Post(title=title, category=category, type=type,
                           subtype=subtype, bedroom=bedroom, toilet=toilet,
                           area=area, street=street, availability=availability,
                           totalarea=totalarea, coveredarea=coveredarea,
                           description=description, 
                           images=image,
                           bathroom=bathroom, short=short,
                           currencyfield=currencyfield, url=url
                    )
            my.save()

      return render(request,"estateapp/done.htm")

   else:

        return render(request,"estateapp/pro.html")

def save (request):        

    return render(request, 'pro.htm', {'form': form})


def House(request):
    
    return render(request, 'estateapp/House.html')


def test(request):
    return render(request,'estateapp/test.html')



def House(request):
    post = PostImage.objects.all()
    posts = []
    return render(request, 'estateapp/House.html', {'posts': posts})
```

This is my forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Post
from django.forms import ModelForm

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
      class Meta:
              model = Post
              fields = '__all__'
            
              name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'my-class'}))
```

This is my models.py

```
from tokenize import Number
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.utils import timezone
from django.utils.html import format_html
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.views.generic import View

# Create your models here.
class Post(models.Model):
      title = models.CharField(max_length= 100, default ="")
      
      short = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")

      CHOICES = [('1', 'For Rent'), ('2', 'For Sale'), ('3', 'Short-Let')]
      category = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=CHOICES, default='1')

      CHOICES = [('1', 'House'), ('2', 'Land'), ('3', 'commercial property'), ('4', 'Warehouses'), ('5', 'Fuel Stations')]
      type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=CHOICES, default='1' )

      
      CHOICES = [('1', 'Duplexes'), ('2', 'Block Of Flats'), ('3', 'Detached Duplexes'), ('4', 'Bungalow'), ('5', 'Mini Flats'), ('6', 'Semi detached Duplexes')]
      subtype = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=CHOICES, default='1')

      CHOICES = [('1', '1'), ('2', '2'), ('3', '3'), ('4', '4'), ('5', '5'), ('6', '6'),('7', '6+')]
      bedroom = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=CHOICES, default='1')

      CHOICES = [('1', '1'), ('2', '2'), ('3', '3'), ('4', '4'), ('5', '5'), ('6', '6'),('7', '6+')]
      toilet = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=CHOICES, default='1')
         
      CHOICES = [('1', '1'), ('2', '2'), ('3', '3'), ('4', '4'), ('5', '5'), ('6', '6'),('7', '6+')]
      bathroom = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=CHOICES, default='1')

      area = models.CharField(max_length= 100, default ="")
      street = models.CharField(max_length= 100, default ="")
      availability = models.CharField(max_length= 100, default ="")
      totalarea = models.PositiveBigIntegerField(default=0)
      coveredarea = models.PositiveBigIntegerField(default=0)
      description = models.TextField(max_length=1000, default=0)
      currencyfield = models.CharField(max_length= 100, default=0)
      
      url = models.URLField(default="")
      author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="1")

      images = models.FileField(default=0)
      sc1 = models.FileField(default=0)
      sc2 = models.FileField(default=0)
      sc3 = models.FileField(default=0)
      sc4 = models.FileField(default=0)


      def _str_(self):
             return self.title


      def get_absolute_url(self):
           return reverse ('post:detail',kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
 
class PostImage(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    images = models.FileField(upload_to='estateapp/images/dp')
 
    def __str__(self):
        return self.post.title
```

this is my admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Post, PostImage

from .forms import PostForm


class PostImageAdmin(admin.StackedInline):
    model = PostImage


class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    inlines = [PostImageAdmin]
 
    class Meta:
       model = Post


class PostImageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass


admin.site.register(Post, PostAdmin)
admin.site.register(PostImage )
```

This is the listings page

```
 {% for post in posts %}
         <div class="house">

            <div class="house-img">
                
                <img src="{{ post.images }}" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="house-info">
                <p>{{ post.title }}</p>
                <h3>{{ post.short }}</h3>
                <p> <i class="fa-solid fa-bed"></i> {{ post.bedroom }} Bedrooms <i class="fa-solid fa-bath"></i> {{ post.bathroom }} Bathrooms  <i class="fa-solid fa-toilet"></i>  {{ post.toilet }} Toilets</p>
                <i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i>
                <i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i>
                <i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i>
                <i class="fa-solid fa-star-half-stroke"></i>
                <i class="fa-regular fa-star"></i>
                <div class="house-price">
                <h4>₦{{ post.currencyfield }}<span>/Yr</span></h4>
                <div class="notice-row">
                  <i class="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-thumbs-up"></i><p>423 Upvote</p>
                  <i class="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-thumbs-down"></i><p>32 Downvote</p>
                </div>
                
                </div>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="https://wa.me/+2347064453868"><i class="fa-brands fa-whatsapp"></i></a>   <p>Whatsapp</p>  </li>
                    <li> <a href="tel:+2347064453868"><i class="fa-solid fa-phone"></i></a><p>Phone</p></li>
                    <li> <i class="fa-brands fa-telegram"></i> <p>Telegram</p></li>
                    <li> <i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i> <p>Instagram</p></li>
                </ul> 
            </div>
        </div>
    
         {% endfor %}
```

this is the post page(where users will add thier properties)

```
<form action=""  onsubmit="return checkForBlank()" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {{form}}  
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="deal">
                <div class="row" >
                    <div class="col-2">
                        <h5 for="subcim" >Title</h5>
                        <input type="text" id="info" placeholder="E.g 5 Bedroom Detached Duplex" name="title" onkeyup="myFunctions()">
                        <span class="error_form" id="ren_error_message"></span>
                        <p id="punctuation"></p>
                    </div> 
                   
                   <div class="dropdown">
                    <h5>Category</h5>
                       <select id="drop"  name="category">
                              <option>For Rent</option>
                              <option>For Sale</option>
                              <option>Short-Let</option>
                              
                          </select>
                       </div>
                      
                       </div>
                       <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-2">
                            <h5>Type</h5>
                           <select class="selle" id="select1"  name="type" onchange="disableSelect2()">    
                                <option value="house"> House</option>
                                <option id="land" value="land">Land</option>
                                <option value="commercial property">Commercial Property</option>
                                <option value="wareehouse">Warehouses</option>
                                <option value="fuel stations">Fuel Stations</option>
                                            
                              </select>
                        </div>
            
                       <div class="dropdown">
                        <h5>Subtype</h5>
                           <select id="select2" name="subtype">
                                  <option>Duplexes</option>
                                  <option>Block Of Flats</option>
                                  <option>Detached Duplexes</option>
                                  <option>Bungalow</option>
                                  <option>Mini Flats</option>
                                  <option>Semi detached Duplexes</option>
                              </select>
                           </div>
                           </div>
                           <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-2">
                                <h5>Area/Locality</h5>
                                <input type="text" id="area" placeholder="E.g Lekki Lagos " name="area">
                        <span class="error_form" id="ren-area_error_message"></span>
    
                            </div>
                
                           <div class="dropdown">
                            <h5>Bedrooms</h5>
                               <select id="select3" name="bedroom">
                                <option> 1</option>
                                <option>2</option>
                                <option>3</option>
                                <option>4</option>
                                <option>5</option>
                                <option>6</option>
                                <option>6+</option>
                                      
                                  </select>
                               </div>
                               
                       
                              
                               </div>
                               <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-2">
                                    <h5>Street</h5>
                                    <input type="text" id="street" placeholder="E.g Denro street " name="street">
                                    <span class="error_form" id="ren-street_error_message" ></span>       
                                </div>
                               <div class="dropdown">
                                <h5>Toilets</h5>
                                   <select id="select4" name="toilet">    
                                    <option> 1</option>
                                    <option>2</option>
                                    <option>3</option>
                                    <option>4</option>
                                    <option>5</option>
                                    <option>6</option>
                                    <option>6+</option>
                                          
                                 </select>
                                   </div>
                    
                                   </div>


                                   <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-2">
                                        <h5>Short-Description</h5>
                                        <input type="text" id="short" placeholder="E.g 5 Bedroom Detached Duplex With a Bq for Rent "  maxlength=`

"50" name="short">
                                        <span class="error_form" id="ren-short_error_message" ></span>       
                                    </div>
                                   <div class="dropdown">
                                    <h5>Bathrooms</h5>
                                       <select id="select4" name="bathroom">    
                                        <option> 1</option>
                                        <option>2</option>
                                        <option>3</option>
                                        <option>4</option>
                                        <option>5</option>
                                        <option>6</option>
                                        <option>6+</option>
                                              
                                     </select>
                                       </div>
                        
                                       </div>           
        <hr>
                                   <div class="row" id="second">
                                    <div class="column">
                                        <h5>Price</h5>
                                       <input type="text" name="currencyfield" id="price"  placeholder="Amount">
                                     <span class="error_form" id="ren_price-area_message"  ></span>
                                     <span id="words"></span>
                                            
                                       
                                        
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="column">
                                        <h5 id="tots">Total Area</h5>
                                        <input type="number"  id="total-area" name="totalarea" placeholder="Sqm">
                                     <span class="error_form" id="ren_error-area_message"></span>
    
        
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="column">
                                        <h5 id="tots">Covered Area</h5>
                                        <input type="number" id="covered-area"  name="coveredarea" placeholder="Sqm">
                                     <span class="error_form" id="ren_error-covered_message"></span>
    
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="row" id="third">
                                    <div class="column" id="avail">
                                        <h5>Availability</h5>
                                        <input type="text" id="info-1"   placeholder="Available,Rented,Sold" name="availability">
                                     <span class="error_form" id="ren avail_message"></span>
                                        
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="column" id="col">
                                        <h5>Add Google Map</h5>
                                        <input type="url"  id="map" name="url" >
                                     <span class="error_form" id="ren_map_message"></span>
    
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                       <div class="description">
                       <h5>Description</h5>
                 <textarea id="message" name="description" rows="2" placeholder="Description Of The Property"></textarea>
                 <span class="error_form" id="ren_message"></span>
    
                   </div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="btn" onclick="showImages()">Done</div>
                   <!-----------Images---------------->
<div class="images" id="images">        
<label class="label"> 
    <input type="file" id="image_input"  name="images"   multiple  accept="image/png, image/jpg, image/jpeg">
    <span>Select Multiple Images</span>
</label>
  
<div class="row-img">
    <div class="col-img"> 
          <div id="display_image"  ></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-img">
      <div id="display_image-1" ></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-img">
      <div id="display_image-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-img">
      <div id="display_image-3"></div>
  </div>
      </div>
      
  <div class="row-img">
      <div class="col-img">
            <div id="display_image-4"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-img" >
        <div id="display_image-5" ></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-img">
        <div id="display_image-6"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-img">
        <div id="display_image-7"></div>
    </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn2"> Post &#859;</button>

         </form>
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

[how to create model with alot of images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68076883/how-do-i-create-a-model-that-stores-multiple-images-in-relation-to-another-model)

and in the django admin add as many images as you want in the images model and link it to the model you want :)
(you dont need to add classes in admin.py just admin.site.register(modelname)